# React conditional classnames

Tags: reactjs

I need to have a className of an item based on a list of conditions. What is the best way of doing this? Right now I have an array and I push the className to the array.

```
const classNames = [];

    if (alarm?.code === 'urgent') {
      classNames.push(styles.yellow);
    } else if (alarm?.code === 'error') {
      classNames.push(styles.red);
    } else if (alarm?.code === 'disabled') {
      classNames.push(styles.grey);
    } else if (alarm?.severity === 'info') {
      classNames.push(styles.blue);
    }
```

Then I add it to the element like this:

```
<div className={[...classNames]}></div>
```

My question is mainly, what is the difference between setting the classNames like this compared to using useState and useEffect?

Comment: Not sure if its the best way but alternatively you can do it this way     
alarm?.code === 'urgent' && styles.openButton and so on

Comment: I think that method would make it much harder to read and alot more extra code

Answer (score 2):

You can check [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package (it is also recommended by React official documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#how-do-i-add-css-classes-to-components))

install with npm

```
npm install classnames --save
```

and use as

```
   const code = alarm?.code;
   const severity = alarm?.severity;

   <div
     className={classNames({
        yellow: code === 'urgent',
        red: code === 'error',
        grey: code === 'disabled',
        blue: severity === 'info'
     })} 
   </div>
```

Comment: I cant be using extra packages I shouldve included it in the question

Answer (score 0):

There is a [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) npm module that does this.  Or make a simple utility.

```
export const classnames = (...args) => args.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
```

Either would be used like

```
<div className={classnames(classNames)}>...</div>
```

Edit - Actually for this one, just separate out the classnames

```
const classNames = {
  urgent: styles.yellow,
  error: styles.red
  disabled: styles.grey
  info: styles.blue
}

<div className={classNames[alarm?.code]}></div>
```

In response to your question:

> My question is mainly, what is the difference between setting the classNames like this compared to using useState and useEffect?

`useState` and `useEffect` are hooks designed to hold state between renders. If you need to trigger a re-render or take action on a change, then that's when you'd use those hooks.  I don't see a need for those with classnames in this case.

Comment: I cant be using extra packages I shouldve included it in the question